# Unable to build Cassandra source

Tags: ant, cassandra

I have cloned Cassandra from github https://github.com/apache/cassandra 
however I am unable to "ant build" the poject I am getting this error

```
maven-ant-tasks-retrieve-build:
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'xmlenc:xmlenc:pom:0.52:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:pom:3.0.1:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:pom:6.1.26:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:pom:6.1.26:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'tomcat:jasper-runtime:pom:5.5.12:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'tomcat:jasper-compiler:pom:5.5.12:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:pom:6.1.14:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:pom:6.1.14:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'commons-el:commons-el:pom:1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:pom:0.7.1:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.sf.kosmosfs:kfs:pom:0.3:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'hsqldb:hsqldb:pom:1.8.0.10:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:pom:1.0.1:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.5.2:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:pom:1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:pom:3.4:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.antlr:ST4:pom:4.0.4:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:pom:1.8.8:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:pom:1.8.8:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:pom:2.3:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:pom:4.1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:pom:4.6:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] Building ant file: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/build-dependencies.xml
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:pom:6.1.26:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:pom:6.1.26:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:pom:6.1.14:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:pom:6.1.14:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'commons-el:commons-el:pom:1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:pom:0.7.1:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:pom:3.4:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.antlr:ST4:pom:4.0.4:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:pom:1.8.8:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:pom:1.8.8:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:pom:2.3:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.tukaani:xz:pom:1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:pom:4.1.0:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:pom:4.6:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] Building ant file: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/build-dependencies-sources.xml
     [copy] Copying 63 files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars
     [copy] Copying 38 files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/sources
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:pom:4.1:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'jaxen:jaxen:pom:1.1-beta-8:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:pom:0.7.1.201405082137:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:pom:0.7.1.201405082137:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
     [copy] Copying 12 files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars
    [unzip] Expanding: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137.jar into /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars

check-gen-cql3-grammar:

gen-cql3-grammar:
     [echo] Building Grammar /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/Cql.g  ...

build-project:
     [echo] apache-cassandra: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 45 source files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/thrift
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/ST4-4.0.4.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/asm-commons-4.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/commons-el-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/guava-16.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jersey-server-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jets3t-0.7.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jetty-6.1.26.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jna-4.1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jopt-simple-4.6.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/kfs-0.3.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/org.jacoco.core-0.7.1.201405082137.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/org.jacoco.report-0.7.1.201405082137.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/paranamer-2.3.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.openjdk.jmh.generators.BenchmarkProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
    [javac] 1 warning
    [javac] Compiling 1169 source files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/main
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/ST4-4.0.4.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/asm-commons-4.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/commons-el-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/guava-16.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jersey-server-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jets3t-0.7.1.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jetty-6.1.26.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jna-4.1.0.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jopt-simple-4.6.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/kfs-0.3.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/org.jacoco.core-0.7.1.201405082137.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/org.jacoco.report-0.7.1.201405082137.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/paranamer-2.3.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] error: error reading /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/lib/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.openjdk.jmh.generators.BenchmarkProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
    [javac] 1 warning

createVersionPropFile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/src/resources/org/apache/cassandra/config
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/src/resources/org/apache/cassandra/config/version.properties
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/main

BUILD FAILED
/home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build.xml:815: Warning: Could not find file /home/adelin/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/main/META-INF/hotspot_compiler to copy.
```

Any suggestions ?!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this twice.

The first time, "ant realclean" (which removes cached build-time dependencies as well as Cassandra classes) fixed it.

The second time, I had to go farther and "rm -rf ~/.m2" which removes the local Maven cache.

Comment: specifically I deleted `~.m2/repository/org` since folder size was 9G and I didn't want to have to reimport everything.